# How do I disable Ubuntu Authenticate popup that is used to elevate privileges?

Tags: ubuntu, security

How do I disable Ubuntu Authenticate popup that is used to elevate privileges?

Please do not put answers telling that this is a security issue, the purpose of this question is **how** and **not why**.

Answer (score 5):

Added to `/etc/sudoers`

`yourusername ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL`

Having been a Unix veteran for 20 years, long before the inception of Ubuntu, I too don't need another lecture about root access, to be found everywhere searching for simple information.

No matter what the docs say, even now with 11.10 the damn popup appears every few minutes when I have dozens of software-center installs queued.  So much for trying to get that done overnight.

Another thing I often resort to is `sudo -i` to a root shell from the terminal to run  `software-center` or other common gui apps (like gparted) that otherwise just love to popup modal password dialogs.

Answer (score 1):

Strange question but here's two ideas:

a) enable root user assigning a password: sudo passwd root

b) log in as root

Another one would be tweak the sudoers file:

Open a terminal and digit:

sudo visudo

And move the big paragraph to the end , remove the # in front of sudo and add yourself to a sudo group

ps
If you want to keep it simple add under:

root    ALL=(ALL) ALL

yourusername    ALL=(ALL) ALL

Comment: I'm really interested about `b)`. Where is the big paragraph you are talking about?

Answer (score 1):

Just use your command with sudo

For example:

```
systemctl start wg-quick@myenv.service
```

Ask for password with Auth

```
sudo systemctl start wg-quick@myenv.service
```

Not asking for...